Hibernate @CreationTimeStamp puts LocalDateTime, not Instant...? WHY?
This is my versions:
openjdk-11
'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.16'
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' version
'2.7.16'
'org.hibernate:hibernate-core' version '5.6.15.Final'
mysql version 8.0
Here is my problem:
When I make entity, I'm using hibernate annotion @CreationTimeStamp to record creation time.
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
public class BookClub {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long creatorId;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BookClubStatus status;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String profileImageUrl;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", nullable = false)
    private Instant createdTime;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private Instant closedTime;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private Instant upcomingGatheringTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookClub")
    private List<BookClubMember> bookClubMembers = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookClub")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}

However when I checked logs createdTime in test codes and the time in db are different.
When I checked logs createdTime in test codes and the time in db are different.

Time in test codes

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        book_club
        (closed_time, created_time, creator_id, name, profile_image_url, status, upcoming_gathering_time) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2024-04-19 16:51:02.209 TRACE 70219 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2024-04-19 16:51:02.210 TRACE 70219 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2024-04-19T07:51:02.208147Z]
2024-04-19 16:51:02.210 TRACE 70219 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2024-04-19 16:51:02.211 TRACE 70219 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [name]
2024-04-19 16:51:02.211 TRACE 70219 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [image.url]
2024-04-19 16:51:02.211 TRACE 70219 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [OPEN]
2024-04-19 16:51:02.211 TRACE 70219 --- [    Test worker] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]


Time in db log(time saved in db is same)

2024-04-19T07:51:02.220193Z         8 Query     insert into book_club (closed_time, created_time, creator_id, name, profile_image_url, status, upcoming_gathering_time) values (null, '2024-04-19 16:51:02.208147', 1, 'name', 'image.url', 'OPEN', null)

I can see test code make query I intended. Instant value I wanted.
But in db, the LocalDateTIme value is inserted.(I'm Korean so 9 hours are added)
I saw @CreationTimestamp javadoc, but it doesn't explain when or how query is made.I want to know why this difference is made.
+++ I know I can solve this problem with setting my OS timezone to UTC, or using JpaAuditing.
Also, I tested same codes with Springboot version 3.x with java 17.
At that time, this problem doesn't happen.
I just want to know the reason why this happens. :) thx

Does this also happen when you set/store a closedTime? If not, the reason may be the annotation @CreationTimestamp, which does not consider time zones or offsets (at least it didn't do so in older versions of hibernate). Here's an answer to a similar question

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You should familiarize yourself with how mysql works with a data type like time, documentation

MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.
(This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default,
the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The
time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time
zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store.
If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and
retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value
you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for
conversion in both directions. The current time zone is available as
the value of the time_zone system variable. For more information, see
Section 7.1.15, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”.

